# Upgrading mysql-client-core-5.5 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Alright, so I need to upgrade our server's version of MySQL, and I'm not certain how to go about it.

When I'm logged in to the server (which is using Ubuntu 14.04), and type `mysql-v`, I get the following:

- mysql-client-core-5.5
- mariadb-client-core-5.5
- mysql-client-core-5.6
- percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5

In a phpinfo() page I have set up on one of the applications on the server, it says (among other things)

MySQL

- Client API version   5.5.62

Now, ideally, I only need to upgrade this to 5.7 (the database for all of this is using MySQL 5.7.33).

But I'm not sure how to proceed. I've found several pages indicating what is a possible upgrade path, but I don't know for certain if that's what I need to do. (Example page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7)

As a side note, mysql does not appear to be a service on this server. That is, when I type `service --status-all`, mysql is not listed as a service (running, stopped, or unknown).

I haven't done anything yet. What I'm looking for is advice.... namely, is the linked page above, what I need to do, or something close to that? (I do plan on creating a database backup file using MySQL Workbench or some other utility before doing anything, of course.)

Comment: Seems like https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7 has plenty of answers. If you have questions about those answers, I'd suggest commenting there rather than opening a new question here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it already has answers at https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7 and any further questions the OP has should be asked there in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, that's the page I linked in my post. I'm just wondering if, considering that right now, mysql isn't listed as a service on the server, if that's the correct way to do it.

Comment: I would suggest asking in a comment on those answers.